# Send tweet using 'enter' key (Greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, twitter, textarea, greasemonkey

I'm attempting to create a Greasemonkey script that can submit a tweet when a user hits the 'enter' key.  I've gotten this to work fine on a simple HTML page (with the help of a few excellent tips on this site).  However, when I try to use the code on my twitter page, the alert only fires if a tweet is not currently being authored.

```
document.onkeyup = function(event){                 
    var keyCode;    
    if (window.event) // IE/Safari/Chrome/Firefox(?)
    {
        keyCode = event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (event.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    {
        keyCode = event.which;
    }   

    if (keyCode == 13){
    alert("Enter pressed");
    }
}
```

My next thought was to test for a more specific keypress event.  So I tried testing for a key event within the new tweet textarea:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-anywhere-tweet-box-editor")[0].onkeyup = function(event)
```

...but this event never seems to fire.  I also tried grabbing the element by tag:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].onkeyup = function(event)
```

...but not dice there either.  I wonder if this has to do with the fact that the new tweet window is not loaded from the get-go at window.onload().  Thoughts?

Comment: could you post your full GM script?

Answer (score 0):

I got it thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283923/greasemonkey-with-jquery-how-to-write-the-greasemonkey-script-to-modify-page-do).  I've also posted the full Greasemonkey script [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/131145).

```
setInterval (function() { checkForTweetbox (); }, 500);

function checkForTweetbox () {
    var tweetbox = document.querySelector ('div.tweet-box textarea');   //check for new tweet window
    if (tweetbox) {
        if (! tweetbox.weHaveProcessed) {
            tweetbox.weHaveProcessed    = true;
//          alert ('New tweet-box found!');
        }
    }   
    tweetbox.onkeydown = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){                                        //13 = Enter keycode
            document.querySelector ('a.primary-btn').click();           //there must be at least one character in the textarea  
        }
    }           
}
```